# As3 Referencing a class from timeline

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I cannot figure out what is going on?  I can import other classes to the timeline and use them just fine, but this class is giving me major problems?  I am parsing XML data from my server on it and it is giving me errors that look like this.

The timeline reference and usage:

```
     import networkScores;

     var network:networkScores = new networkScores();
     addChild(network);

     score1Textfield.text = network.score1.toString();
```

The class definition:

```
 package 
 {
          import flash.net.URLLoader;
          import flash.net.URLRequest;
          import flash.events.Event;
          import flash.display.MovieClip;

         public class networkScores extends MovieClip
         {
                 public var myXML:XML, myXMLNames:XML;
                 public var xmlLoaderScores = new URLLoader();
                 public var score1:int;

                 public function networkScores()
                 {
                     xmlLoaderScores.addEventListener(
                                Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedScores);
                     xmlLoaderScores.load(new URLRequest("pathtoxmlfile"));
                 }

                 public function xmlLoadedScores(e:Event):void
                 {
                      myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
                      var qName1:QName = new QName(
                            "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "score1");
                      score1 = myXML.descendants(qName1)[0].toString();
                 }
            
        }

     }
```

The errors I am getting:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 149 1119: Access of possibly undefined property score1 through a reference with static type networkScores.
>
> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type networkScores to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Is this a casting issue?

how can I fix this?

Comment: could you tell me which line got which error?

Comment: Im sorry, yes, the addChild(network); line received the 1067 error, and the network.score1.toString(); line got the 1119 error.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I think flash can't find the class networkScores's definition. Where is the networkScores.as file?

Comment: the network scores file is in the same directory as my .xfl file

Comment: @Scientific xfl file? Only fla and mxml file I have used. Is it the same as the fla?

Comment: The XFL file is an uncompressed file format that uses XML files like the DOMDocument.xml at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timeline should not be trying to refer to the document Class. The document Class should control everything. There are several ways to know when an object has been added to the stage and is ready to be addressed (such as listening for added to stage). Once you know the object has been added and you *also* know your xml has returned, you can then populate a variable on the child object that you've exposed in *its* document Class.  For more on this, check out this blog post http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html , and the accompanying code here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-code-for-oop-timeline-insideria.html .

EDITED to show code:

The code for it might look something like this:

```
package {
   public class Main extends MovieClip {
      private var _stageInstance:StageInstance;
      private var _score:String;
      private var _loader:URLLoader;//hold loader in memory so it doesn't gc before it returns
      //by using a getter/setter pair, we know when Flash has added the instance to the stage
      public function get stageInstance():StageInstance{
          return _stageInstance;
      }
      public function set stageInstance(value:StageInstance):void {
         _stageInstance = value;
         if (_stageInstance != null && _score != null) {
             _stageInstance.score = _score;
         }
      }
      public function onScoreLoaded(e:Event):void {
         myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
         var qName1:QName = new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "score1");
         _score = myXML.descendants(qName1)[0].toString();
         if (stageInstance != null) {
            stageInstance.score = _score;
         }
      }
      public function Main() {
         _loader = new URLLoader();
         _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onScoreLoaded);
         _loader.load(new URLRequest('pathToXML'));
      }
   }

}

package {
   public Class StageInstance extends MovieClip {
       pubic var score1TextField:TextField;//populated by Flash Player
       private vare _score:String;
       //note how the setter here is doing something useful, not just passing through the value
       public function get score():String {
          return _score;
       }
       public function set score(value:String):void {
          _score=value;
          score1TextField.text=score;
       }
       public function StageInstance() {
          super();
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: Right, but the main document Class should be orchestrating the relationship between the data Class and the timeline Class.  The timeline object should NOT be trying to handle this.

Comment: Yes. There are two types of developers, the type who care about best practice and those who care about getting it to work some kind of way. I tend to assume that if you're asking on a forum like StackOverflow you'd at least like to know what the best practice is.

Comment: Hello, and thank you everyone for your input.  Like AsTheWormTurns said, I am not trying to reference the networkScores.as file as a linkage class identifier from my library, just simply from the timeline.  I have seen classes referenced this way before, and I have seen classes referenced the way Amy speaks of. I did not know which one was correct and assumed that I could use both methods.  Thanks Scientific

Comment: @Sceintific: Yes, you will see files that do all kinds of things that are bad practice. The thing is, AS2 forced developers into a lot of bad habits, and many of them have yet to recover. New developers, seeing what they do (and guided by the snippets feature), jump right into the bad habits without even realizing what's happening.

Comment: @Scientific: You should have a document Class for your timeline Class that is now trying to manage the business logic.  That way, a higher up Class (like the main Document Class) can determine both that the XML is loaded and your timeline Class is ready and then make the necessary changes to your timeline Class.

Comment: No, that won't work, because you can't call a constructor on a timeline instance, and also because you have to wait for the XML to load before you even know what the score is. It doesn't matter whether you call the Class StageInstance or ScoreContainer. I called it StageInstance to point out that it was the timeline instance that was currently trying to manage this for itself.

Comment: I don't think you have. When the Flash player is instantiating the Class for you (which is what happens when you have a timeline instance), how do you get it to place the value you want into the constructor function (assuming the xml has already loaded and you have it)?

Comment: The original poster was asking to do this using a _timeline instance_. I'm not saying that your solution won't work, but it involves constructing the instance yourself--not instantiating it on the stage.  I understand you just fine, but I think you're not understanding me. If you read the links I posted in my answer, you might.

Comment: Hello everyone, sorry for my delay, but thank you very much for the help!  I set up my project now using a document class system as described by Amy and it is working properly now.  I was for sure one of those developers that jumped right in learning bad practices. Thanks Again Scientific